# Is it possible to set up a `@Published` in an `ObservableObject` even more type-safe?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

So I have an ObservableObject which has an input-binding named `query` and a `@Published` output of search results named `output`. It looks something like this:

```swift
class SearchViewModel: ObservableObject {
    typealias Output = Result<[SearchResult], ApiError>

    // `@Input` is similar to `@Published` except
    // that it doesn't cause SwiftUI to re-render.
    @Input var query = ""

    @Published private(set) var output = Output.success([])
    
    private let loader = SearchResultsLoader()

    init() {
        configureDataPipeline()
    }

    func configureDataPipeline() {
        $query
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .removeDuplicates()
            // ... map to results from self.loader ...
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: &$output)
    }
}
```

Now I guess this is all fine, but it's not like *perfectly* type-safe. I'm coming from javascript with RxJS and there we would do something like:

```js
const output$ = query$.pipe(/* transformations here */)
```

And the beautiful thing about that, is two things basically:

1. Everything you need to know about `output$` is right there in its declaration. You don't need to look for other mentions of `output$` to determine what `output$` is and how it behaves.
2. Because `output$` is a `const` you can rest assured that `output$` will never be changed into something other than what it was declared as.

I would *really* like it if I can get these same things in my Swift code. Is that possible? Maybe by writing my own property wrapper that slightly differs from `@Published` in that it accepts an `AnyPublisher` and then internally `assign`s it? Or would that interfere with using the property in SwiftUI?

Or is this whole thing a fool's errand?

Comment: I don't think creating your own property wrapper would work here. SwiftUI is very "picky" about what changes to observe. It is very hard to wrap `Published` into something that you can control. I would consider writing a macro, or manually sending `objectWillChange`, which is less fine-grained than `Published`.

Comment: We would have to see how Inout was created

Answer (score 0):

What seems closest to the RxJS you posted is something along these lines:

```
class SearchViewModel {
  typealias Output = Result<[SearchResult], APIError>

  let output: AnyPublisher<Output, Never>
  private let results = CurrentValueSubject<Output, Never>(Output.success([]))

  init() {
    output = results./* pipeline building here */.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

You loose the ability to handle changes to "output" using Swift UI's syntax sugaring but you could use an `onReceive` based on `output` to respond to changes.